# iOS, Objective C - NSURLConnection and asynchronious examples, default behavior and best practices?

Tags: objective-c, ios5, nsurlconnection

I have been working with a few applications that deal with NSURLConnections. While researching best practices I have noticed a lot of examples online showing how to use `NSOperation` and `NSOperationQueue` to deal with this.

I have also noticed on stackoverflow a few examples that show initializing the connection as synchronous and asynchronous using the class methods of `NSURLConnection`: `sendAsynchronousRequest` and `sendSynchronousRequest`.

Currently I am doing my initialization as follows:

```
[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

While doing this I have monitored the main thread and the calls to the delegate methods:

`connectionDidFinishLoading`, `connectionDidReceiveResponse`, `connectionDidReceiveData` and `connectionDidFailWithError`

Everything I have read in Apples documentation and my tests prove to me that this is asynchronous by default behavior.

I would like to know from more experienced Objective C programmers when the other options would be used for either a best practice, or just be more correct than what I see as the most simplistic way to get async behavior?

This is my first question I have posted on here, if more information is needed please ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method you list are the traditional means of asynchronous transfer and an app that uses them will be efficient in processor (and hence power) use.

The `sendAsynchronousRequest` method is a relatively new addition, arriving in iOS 5. In terms of best practice there's little other than style to differentiate between it and the data delegate methods other than that a request created with the latter can be cancelled and a request created with the former can't. However the tidiness and hence the readability and greater improbability of bugs of the block-based `sendAsynchronousRequest` arguably give it an edge if you know you're not going to want to cancel your connections.

As a matter of best practice, `sendSynchronousRequest` should always be avoided. If you use it on the main thread then you'll block the user interface. If you use it on any other thread or queue that you've created for a more general purpose then you'll block that. If you create a special queue or thread for it, or post it to an `NSOperationQueue` then you'll get no real advantages over a normal asynchronous post and your app will be less power efficient per Apple's standard WWDC comments.

References to `sendSynchronousRequest` are probably remnants of pre-iOS 5 patterns. Anywhere you see a `sendSynchronousRequest`, a `sendAsynchronousRequest` could be implemented just as easily and so as to perform more efficiently. I'd guess it was included originally because sometimes you're adapting code that needs to flow in a straight line and because there were no blocks and hence no 'essentially a straight line' way to implement an asynchronous call. I really can't think of any good reason to use it now.

Comment: Excellent answer, I appreciate it. I have noticed quite a few areas of IOS that you can do the same thing in different ways. It seems as the SDK evolves Apple continues to improve and give the developers more choices. Very nice, but tough to keep up with.

Answer (score 3):

Synchronous is bad bad bad. Try to avoid it. That will block up your main thread if the data transfer is large, thus resulting in an unresponsive UI.

Yes, it is possible to dispatch a synchronous call onto a different thread, but then you have to access any UI elements back on the main thread and it is a mess.

Normally I just use the delegate methods you have described - it is straightforward, and NSURLConnection already handles the asynchronous call for you away from the main thread. All you need to do is implement the simple delegate methods! It's a little more code, but you always want to go asynchronous. Always. And when it is finished loading, use the information you get to update the UI from the finishedLoading delegate method.

You also have the option of using blocks now, but I can't speak for how well those work or even how to use them well. I'm sure there's a tutorial somewhere - the delegate methods are just so easy to implement.